# Function app not reachable

Tags: azure-functions

I keep getting the following error popping up repeatedly while on the function app blade. Can't find anything online that allows me to resolve it. Any ideas on whats happening and why?

> Error:
>
> We are unable to reach your function app (Internal Server Error).
> Please try again later.

#### Edit #1

Have found that the `host.json` file has an empty array -> `{}`. Don't know if this matters.

Comment: Normally, those popups should contain a session ID, which helps diagnosis. If you have one, please add it to the question.

Comment: I once faced a similar problem. It was hard to debug and eventually we figured out that it was happening because the json inside function.json file was invalid. 
@DavidEbbo It will be better if such errors are thrown explicitly with some detail, instead of an 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: Yes, error handling can be improved in some situations. But first we need to understand the situation, and we can't do that without the session id :)

Comment: Adrian, can you provide the information requested by David? An empty JSON object in host.json is normal, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Sorry didn't take note of session id, and didn't post because I didn't know if it was sensitive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application settings I was using the drop-down box to change the Python version.

Once this was changed the error started occurring.

I deleted the function app, and cleared all files from the file storage account, then created a new function app. I tried using the different versions of python to see if it was version related, however the same error kept occurring (even if selecting 2.7). I repeated this for both versions of python in the drop-down and got the same behaviour.

To resolve, I deleted the function app, deleted files from file storage in the storage account, recreated the app, and did not make any selection of the python version (it is set to off).

Even though the python version is set to off, 2.7 is still avaiable for use, as I have been able to write working functions in python.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. If I 'browse' the public app function site, it says internal error. If I disable python, the internal error disappears, and the pytnon (2.7) functions runs again (but I need 3.4!!)